# How to I apply the zoom transform to my d3 force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed, svg-transforms

Other similar answers I have found on StackOverflow are old and no longer apply to the latest version.

My zoomed function is being called. The `transform` parameter contains:

[image: transform parameter]

I assume I will need to take the information in `transform.transform` and apply it to the `transform` attribute on the svg. The `this` variable contains a reference to the SVG.

What I am not sure about is exactly how to do that...?

```js
    const width = 1000
    const height = 400

    const node_data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
      group: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    }))

    const edge_data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    }))

    const links = edge_data.map((d) => ({ ...d }))
    const nodes = node_data.map((d, index) => ({ id: index, ...d }))
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

    //
    //
    //

    function zoomed(transform) {
      // console.log(` ~ zoomed ~ this:`, this)
      // console.log(` ~ zoomed ~ transform:`, transform)
    }

    const svg = d3.select('#chart').call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed))

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((d) => d.id)
          .distance((d) => 100)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    const link = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#999')
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.6)
      .selectAll()
      .data(links)
      .join('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value))

    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join('circle')
      .attr('r', 16)
      .attr('fill', (d) => color(d.group))

    node.append('title').text((d) => `hello ${d.id}`)

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      node.attr('cx', (d) => d.x).attr('cy', (d) => d.y)
    }

    node.call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended))

    function dragstarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x
      event.subject.fy = event.y
    }

    function dragended(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0)
      event.subject.fx = null
      event.subject.fy = null
    }
```

```css
    .graph {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <svg ref="chart" id="chart" class="graph"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight-forward implementation is:

```
function zoomed(e) {
  zoomG.attr('transform', e.transform); //<-- apply zoom
}

const svg = d3.select('#chart').call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed));  //<-- add zoom behavior
const zoomG = svg.append('g'); //<-- wrap drawing in g to apply zoom on
```

```js
const width = 1000
    const height = 400

    const node_data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
      group: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    }))

    const edge_data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    }))

    const links = edge_data.map((d) => ({ ...d }))
    const nodes = node_data.map((d, index) => ({ id: index, ...d }))
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

    //
    //
    //

    function zoomed(e) {
      zoomG.attr('transform', e.transform); //<-- apply zoome
    }

    const svg = d3.select('#chart').call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed));  //<-- add zoom behavior
    const zoomG = svg.append('g'); //<-- wrap drawing in g to apply zoom on

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((d) => d.id)
          .distance((d) => 100)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    const link = zoomG
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#999')
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.6)
      .selectAll()
      .data(links)
      .join('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value))

    const node = zoomG
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join('circle')
      .attr('r', 16)
      .attr('fill', (d) => color(d.group))

    node.append('title').text((d) => `hello ${d.id}`)

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      node.attr('cx', (d) => d.x).attr('cy', (d) => d.y)
    }

    node.call(d3.drag().on('start', dragstarted).on('drag', dragged).on('end', dragended))

    function dragstarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x
      event.subject.fy = event.y
    }

    function dragended(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0)
      event.subject.fx = null
      event.subject.fy = null
    }
```

```css
.graph {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <svg ref="chart" id="chart" class="graph"></svg>
```